# Pop view controller from Swift class in storyboard based iOS project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on an iOS app using Xcode 6 and Swift. I'm working with storyboard, so I don't have to instantiate a NavigationController in AppDelegate.

But in my applicationDidFinishLaunching, I instantiate a controller to control Philips Hue

```
var window: UIWindow?

var phController:PHController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.phController = PHController()

    return true
}
```

In this PHController I have a heartbeat function, which is checking all 10 seconds if the connection to the Philips Hue Bridge is still alive.
If not (and this could happen all the time, INDEPENDENT from where the user is currently in the app), I would like to pop a view controller (SearchForNewBridgeViewController).

**The question is:
How can I pop/present modally a ViewController from PHController class instantiated when the app did finish launching?**

My idea is to instantiate the PHController with the navigationController:

```
self.phController = PHController(self.navigationController)
```

But my project is as I mentioned Storyboard based, so I don't have a navigationConntroller in my AppDelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution :)

**Solution:**

Instantiate my controller and give AppDelegate as argument:

```
var window: UIWindow?

var phController:PHController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.phController = PHController(delegate:self)

    return true
}
```

Initializer of PHController:

```
var delegate:AppDelegate?

init(delegate:AppDelegate) {
    self.delegate = delegate
    ...

}
```

Present SearchForNewBridgeViewController modally from PHController:

```
func showSearchForNewBridge() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
    var searchForNewBridgeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchForNewBridge") as SearchForNewBridgeViewController
    var navigationController = self.delegate!.window!.rootViewController as UINavigationController
    navigationController.presentViewController(searchForNewBridgeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It's working perfectly for me